# Normal extension, why is $E/\mathbb F_p(t)$ normal?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I have a theorem that says that $E/K$ is a normal extension if $E$ is the splitting field of one separable polynomial $f \in F[X]$.

In an exercise, I have that the splitting field $E$ of $X^p-t$ is normal since $X^p-t$ splits over $E$, the extension $E/\mathbb F_p(t)$ is normal. But $X^p-t$ is not separable, since $X^p-t=(X-\sqrt[p]t)^p$, so the theorem doesn't hold... Any explanation?

Moreover, does $E=\mathbb F_p(t)(\sqrt[p]t)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have written the answer. The point is that $X^p-t$ has a unique root thus its splitting field is normal by definition.

Comment: Ok, but the polynomial is not separable. Whereas the theorem ask for the separability of the polynomial.

Comment: You don't need that by definition, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension